# How to work with tuples in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataset in a pandas dataframe where each cell contains a tuple (1,2), (3, 4)... I would like to write a function which adds the second number to a total_if_one column for each row.How does one achieve this? I am having an issue with this as I am new to pandas and its built in functions.

For example, a pair such as (1, 3) should add 3 to the column: total_if_one. if its (1, 5) it should add 5 to the total_if_one and so forth. these numbers must sum to 8. so the totals column must be 8.